# update query is extremely slow sometimes

Tags: mysql, go

I am using [go-sql-driver](https://github.com/go-sql-driver) in my go micro services, but I found a strange things that update query is extremely slow sometimes. The code as below:

```
......
timeCost1 := int64(time.Now().UnixNano())/int64(time.Millisecond)
updateSQL := "updateSQL UPDATE conv SET  msg_count = ? , client_msg_count = ? , last_msg_content = ? , last_msg_created_on = ?  WHERE id = ?"
// args = [66 33 test 2017-03-29 17:28:29.45927 1489978968]
result, err := db.Exec(updateSQL, args...)
timeCost2 := int64(time.Now().UnixNano())/int64(time.Millisecond)
executeTime = timeCost2 - timeCost1
......
```

the output sql like this:

```
UPDATE conv SET  msg_num = 66 , agent_msg_num = 33 , last_msg_content = 'test' , last_msg_created_on = '2017-03-29 17:28:29.45927'  WHERE id = 1489978968
```

Sometimes, I found the `executeTime` is more than 10 seconds, but I cannot reproduce it, and don't find any slow query in mysql slow_query_log. So I cannot confirm it is mysql problem or go package issue, anyone can give me some good idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unrelated, but unless you are in complete control of what gets put in `%s`, you are prone to SQL injections.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear database/sql escapes parameters

Comment: @AmmarBandukwala when they are input via the `?` operator. I've not seen, nor used `%s` in the driver though, so I assumed it was being assigned via `fmt.Sprintf()`.

Comment: I would suspect a different transaction that locks your table/row at that time. Do you have others sessions/users/apps that access your database?

Comment: Is it real code or you made something up? `"UPDATE conv SET %s WHERE id = ?"` query does not look like it can be `db.Exec`d due to `%s`

Comment: @RayfenWindspear you are right, I am using the `fmt.Sprintf()`

Comment: @Solarflare It is possible, but I didn't find any slow log from mysql slow_query_log, and no deadlock exception.

Comment: Waiting for another transaction doesn't (necessarily) put the query in the slow query log. I would enable the general query log (which logs every query that got sent to the server) and check what other queries got executed shortly before your effect happens; it might point you to some long running query/transaction. Or you find nothing and you can at least exclude this reason.

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks a lot! big help! I enable the query log and find another transaction update the same row. I fix the issue and hope it works!

Comment: @Solarflare We have solved this problem. The reason is that we use a python ORM framework (Sqlalchemy) in another service, but it use the some db with current service, it trigger a unexpected update query, we have removed it , then everything is ok, I really appreciate your help！

Comment: @Solarflare But I have a question: If transaction A want update record R,  a different transaction B locks the R at that time, if deadlock happened, I should found it by `show engine innodb status;` command, but didn't find any deadlock info, if no deadlock, transaction B is processed for a long time (more than 10s) impossible.

Comment: Glad you found it. It's sometimes not easy to find. About deadlocks: waiting is not a deadlock. A [deadlock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlocks.html) is a situation where waiting will not help anymore. E.g. Trans1: update A, Trans2: update B, Trans1: wants to update B (is locked by Trans2->has to wait), Trans2: wants to update A (is locked by Trans1->has to wait). They both would wait forever for each other, so one transaction is rolled back, the other can go on. Your first transaction probably just needed some time and the other just waited, and none got rolled back.